# Bar Chart, problems fetching data with same Month

Tags: mysql

This is my SQL Query for getting the "Patients" that are Negative in either tests and recovery_tests table and at the same time getting the Month where tests_results is recorded.

```sql
SELECT * FROM patient
NATURAL JOIN tests
LEFT JOIN recovery_tests
    ON tests.patient_id=recovery_tests.patient_id
WHERE MONTH(date)='4'
    AND test_results='Negative'
    OR second_test='Negative'
```

But when I change the Month to `( MONTH(date)='1' )` Like the query below

```sql
SELECT * FROM patient
NATURAL JOIN tests
LEFT JOIN recovery_tests
    ON tests.patient_id=recovery_tests.patient_id
WHERE MONTH(date)='1'
    AND test_results='Negative'
    OR second_test='Negative'
```

A Row which contains date: 2020-04-09 keeps on showing even when I try to change the months of the condition like: `MONTH(date)='2' or MONTH(date)='3'` and so on.

How can I write a SQL query to only select the month that the Test Result is recorded?

Comment: Basic logic: `A and B or C` will return true if `C` is true. I think what you want is `A and (B or C)`, where the parenthesized expression will have precedence.

Comment: @El_Vanja correct, this is for operator precedence between AND and OR. Written this way is (A AND B) both togheter or C by itself